# Importing missing package (sun.security.pkcs.PKCS10) automatically in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have to use PKCS10 class into my project. I tried to import sun.security.pkcs.PKCS10; into my activity code but studio shows "Cannot resolve symbol PKCS10" at both places where I have imported it and where I want to instantiat it.
Note: I haven't added any dependency or library (like .jar) to my project.
I want to know whether can it be automatically?

Comment: show full code of class PKCS10

Answer (score 0):

The `class` `sun.security.pkcs10.PKCS10` was removed from the JDK. Using a class that was internal and already removed from the JDK is going a step beyond just using an internal API.

Put this into your `build.gradle` file.

```
compileJava {
    options.forkOptions.javaHome = file(System.properties['java.home'])
}
```

And if this does not work, put this into you build.gradle(app) dependencies.

```
compile group: 'com.sun', name: 'rt', version: '1.5.0_06'
```